# Comparable Generic how to use ist

Tags: java, generics, interface, abstract, comparable

I am very new in Java. I dont get the idea of this `<T extends Comparable<T>>`. I mean why a `T` before extends? Is that not enough to write `extends Comparable<T>`? Why `extends` and not `implements` in javadoc its an interface, right? As I understand `Comparable` compares two objects?

```
public class TopNPrinter<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    private int N;
    private String header;

    public TopNPrinter(int N, String header) {
        this.N = N;
        this.header = header;
    }

    private List<T> getTopN(List<T> list) {
        List<T> copy = new ArrayList<>(list);
        Collections.sort(copy);
        return copy.subList(0, N);
    }
```

Comment: Aside: it's a little better to use `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>` anyway.

Comment: why is it better to use <? super T>>?

Comment: @Sayuri: "why is it better to use <? super T>>" Consider if `Animal extends Comparable<Animal>`, and `Dog extends Animal`, then with `<T extends Comparable<T>>`, `TopNPrinter<Animal>` would compile while `TopNPrinter<Dog>` wouldn't, even though any `Dog` object can compare to any other `Dog` object (as well as other `Animal`s). `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>` fixes that. Another way to look at it is `Comparable` is a "consumer" (`T` is only used as method parameter types), and therefore according to the PECS rule should always be used with a `? super` wildcard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing two things:

First, `extends Comparable<T>` is not for your `TopNPrinter` class (i.e., the class `TopNPrinter` is not intended to implement the `Comparable` interface). 

When you see the syntax `class TopNPrinter<T extends Comparable<T>>`, then you have a generic class that declares a type parameter called `T`. `extends Comparable<T>` limits `T` to types that implement the `Comparable` interface (with `T` being the type argument to the generic `Comparable<T>` interface.

Second:

> Is that not enough to write `extends Comparable<T>`

If you wrote

```
class TopNPrinter extends Comparable<T>
```

Then, unless `T` were an existing type, `T` would be undefined/unknown. So, as mentioned above, `T` is being declared as the generic type parameter. Again, the fundamental problem here is that one needs to understand generics and how generic types are declared. I personally find the [generics faq](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#What%20is%20a%20parameterized%20(or%20generic)%20type?) very helpful for this.

Comment: Thanks alot for your description. I understand it better.